# Having trouble finding the issue of an expressed/formulated requirement

Tags: requirements, requirements-management

I'm studying for an exam (software-engineering) and got stuck with the following question.

*Developing a web application for stock in order to monitor (automatically) and to trade shares. You are responsible for requirement capturing. Explain why the following requirement is not recommendable.*

> The shares should be stored in a relational database.

*Assume that the domain 'share' is defined at another point.*

I appreciate your responses!

Comment: Apparently the answer is that requirements should not contain (technical) solution. Would you agree? 
I never read this anywere lol

Comment: Sorry, this is unanswerable for the community here. We could only guess here what the author of the exam question could have meant, just like you.

Comment: Yes, the theoretical view of the design process is that there must first be a problem before anyone starts considering solutions.  And "recorded in a relational database" is an aspect of the solution space, not the problem space.  In real life you'll see it happen more than once that users specify their solution to you rather than their problem.  It may even be a long time before you hit the first user who actually specifies his *problem*, trusting *you* (the professional) to build the solution.  A very popular version is "I make this spreadsheet like this and I want you to upload it there".

Comment: @ErwinSmout, thx :)

Comment: Perhaps an edit can salvage this question: if the focus is more on why requirements and solutions should be separate or on whether requirements and solutions are separate in practice and less on the specific exam and its question.

Comment: In reality *"The shares should be stored in a relational database"* can be a perfectly valid requirement. Most systems are not created on a "green field". For example, there could be already a relational "enterprise" database and your "customer" or client wants you to integrate all newly create applications into that system. There are more requirements than just the functional business requirements, there are usually also non-functional and/or technical requirements to consider.

Comment: Doc Brown, obviously correct of course, though in such cases the requirement would be stated more precisely and detailed than just "stored in a relational db" (instead e.g. "stored in our currently existing z/OS DB2 system").

Comment: @ErwinSmout: that is precisely the point why hypothetical exam question are not a good fit for this site: they lack so much context that anybody can interpret anything into them.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after hours of deep digging..

The statement is one of implementation and not of need, and it is common to find such statements in requirement specifications. Specifications should state WHAT is needed, not HOW it is to be provided.